# Redirecting to another web page instead of default Url in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to redirect to another Web Page other than DEFAULT URL.This is my code.But I am getting error when I use SetAuthCookie.Its working fine when I use RedirectToLoginPage but the problem is Its Redirecting to defaultUrl. I need to redirect to "WelcomeStaff.aspx"

```
        protected void Buttontbl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (AuthenticateUser(Textusertbl1.Text,textpastbl1.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Textusertbl1.Text, CheckBoxtbl1.Checked);
            Response.Redirect("WelcomeStudent.aspx", true);

        }
        else
        {
           errorlbl.Text="Invalid Username or Password";
        }
        }
```

This is my web.config file.Have specified defaultUrl here.

```
       <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="SelectUser.aspx" defaultUrl="WelcomeStaff.aspx"/>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
       <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
```

Please Help.!! I am new to .Net.Thanks in advance !! This is the error

```
  Server Error in '/' Application.

  The resource cannot be found.

  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have        been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

  Requested URL: /Register/WelcomeStudent.aspx
```

Comment: "But I am getting error when I use SetAuthCookie." Perhaps that error might be meaningul. Please tell us the error so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Even if I remove the defaultURl="WelcomeStaff.aspx" in web.config file Iam getting the same errpr @Jon P

Comment: What directory is "WelcomeStudent.aspx" in? The same as in the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code (aspx.cs)

```
Response.Redirect( FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl );
```

In your webconfig please use ~/path_to_default_page/default_page.aspx

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/member_login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="~/path_to_default_page/default_page.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending your time to solve my problem @Jon P. Could you please tell me why should i use " ~/WelcomeStudent.aspx" because automatically it will search from root folder only Isnt ?

Comment: You should read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne

Answer (score 1):

Change

`Response.Redirect("WelcomeStudent.aspx", true);`

to

`Response.Redirect("~/WelcomeStudent.aspx", true);`

assuming "WelcomeStudent.aspx" is at the root level of the website.

Comment: Thanks a Lot.Its working fine.So can I remove the defaultUrl in web.config file.If I have it in web.config file what is the purpose ? Jon P