# ASP.NET MVC LoginUrl vs DefaultUrl

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

Im developing an application using `ASP.NET MVC` framework, my homepage is not public, so every user has to login in order to access in my site.

In that case, does it make sense that my `LoginUrl` equals my `DefaultUrl`? Also, what's the difference between `DefaultUrl` and my `Default Controller Action`?

By the way, im using `OWIN` to implement the authentication.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

They have different functionality.

LoginUrl defines what is the url of the login.

DefaultUrl defines where the authentication process will take you after login.

The DefaultUrl only defines the route while the DefaultController defines the logic for the Default page itself.

Comment: And why i cant just redirect to home page after the user logs in? Why do i need a DefaultUrl?

Comment: I don't understand very well your question but, as you can see in documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.100).aspx) defaultUrl is an optional attibute. Also you can set same address for loginUrl and defaultUrl.

Comment: Additonally, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395255/redirecting-to-another-web-page-instead-of-default-url-in-asp-net?answertab=active#tab-top, some addresses that using Response.Redirect( FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl ); works to redirect.